# Shared folder with VMware and Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: vmware

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 as a Virtual machine using VMWare Workstation 16 Pro hosted on a Windows 10 Pro computer.

There is an issue with having shared folder between the virtual machine and the host.  It is documented with VMware and the solution involved adding a line to /etc/fstab

When I try to edit this file, I find it is read only.

I tried to change the read and write settings for the file and the directory it is in.

[image: terminnal]

But this did not work and when I opened the file with gedit, it still displayed the file in read-only mode.

Please advise.

Comment: could it be permissions at the windows side?